# How to set ENVREFERENCE when creating a SQL Server job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, jobs

SQL Server 2014 (if it matters)

When I am migrating SSIS packages and jobs between environments, I need to update the `/ENVREFERENCE` parameter to the command for each job step.  Is there anyway to find the correct value and script the job step to use this value.

**Pseudocode**

```
Query for ENVREFERENCE where Environment name = N'QA' -- how to do this?
EXEC sp_update_jobstep 
    @job_name = N'My Job', 
    @step_id = 30, 
    @command= first part + /ENVREFERENCE= value from query + last part;
```

Comment: Does [this answer](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/83747/8783) help ?

Comment: @Kin thanks for the link!  I was looking for a more automated solution that could be used in a CI environment.

Answer (score 4):

I've used code like the following in my job scripts to associate the step with the proper environment:

```
--Call SSIS package. Figure out the server and Environment Reference variables
DECLARE @EnvReference   INT = (SELECT TOP 1 EnvironmentReferenceID FROM SSISDB.rpt.Package WHERE PackagePathName = '\SSISDB\Folder\Project\Package.dtsx\');
DECLARE @Command        VARCHAR(2000) = FORMATMESSAGE(N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\Folder\Project\Package.dtsx\"" /SERVER %s /ENVREFERENCE %i /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E', @@SERVERNAME, @EnvReference);
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'Job Name', 
                @step_id=1, 
                @on_success_action=3, 
                @on_fail_action=3, 
                @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
                @command=@Command, 
                @database_name=N'master', 
                @output_file_name=N'E:\Log\Job.log',
                @flags=40;
```

By the way the view rpt.Package is just this:

```
SELECT  PackagePathName = FORMATMESSAGE('\SSISDB\%s\%s\%s\', F2.name, PJ.name, PK.name),
    EnvironnmentPathName = FORMATMESSAGE('\SSISDB\%s\%s', F.name, E.name),
    EnvironmentReferenceID = ER.reference_id,
    ProjectFolder = F.name,
    Project = PJ.name,
    Package = PK.name,
    EnvironmentFolder = F2.name,
    Environment = E.name
FROM    catalog.folders AS F
    INNER JOIN catalog.environments AS E ON E.folder_id = F.folder_id
    INNER JOIN catalog.environment_references AS ER ON (ER.reference_type = 'A'
            AND ER.environment_folder_name = F.name
            AND ER.environment_name = E.name)
        OR (ER.reference_type = 'R'
            AND ER.environment_name = E.name)
    INNER JOIN catalog.projects AS PJ ON PJ.project_id = ER.project_id AND PJ.folder_id = F.folder_id
    INNER JOIN catalog.packages AS PK ON PK.project_id = PJ.project_id
    INNER JOIN catalog.folders AS F2 ON F2.folder_id = PJ.folder_id
```

Make sure to replace the references: Folder, Project, Package, Job with your own strings.

Comment: Worked like a charm, had to add an extra view but helped all the deployments.